# Meaning of floor in equations

Tags: algorithm, math, analysis, floor

By reading the title it may sound like a silly question, but I have a data structures exam tomorrow and some formulas I need to know for algorithm analysis are read as  `(n – floor(log (n + 1))`. What is the meaning of *floor*?

Thanks

Comment: round down to the nearest whole number

Comment: `floor` rounds down to the next lower integer so (for example) `1.6` would round to `1` and `1.0` will remain `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`floor(x)` is the largest integer not greater than `x`. You can easily find this information on the web, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) for example.

e.g.

```
floor(1.12) = 1  
floor(0.53) = 0
floor(-3.4) = -4
```

One thing that can confuse people is the floor of a negative value. Some might initially think that `floor(-3.4)` is `-3` when in reality it is `-4` by the definition of `floor(x)`.

---

As a note, `floor(x)` is often written as [image].

Answer (score 1):

To round down to the nearest integer value.

Answer (score 0):

For positive numbers: Remove the decimal portion. eg. floor(3.4): 3

For negative numbers: Remove the decimal portion and subtract one. eg. floor(-3.4): -3 - 1 = -4

Hope this helps.!

Comment: This isn't quite true for the negative case, if the number is a negative integer. For example, `floor(-3) = -3`.

Comment: I think @pathfinder666  explained right. But Zéychin misunderstood.